There exists a set of complex numbers $\alpha_n:n\in\mathbb{Z^*}$ such that $x=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z^*}}\alpha_ne^{nx}$?
Note this is an infinite series! I have the same question for $1$, is it possible to have $1=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z^*}}\beta_ne^{nx}$ for some complex coeficients $\beta_n\in\mathbb{C}$?
I am considering these are all functions of the Hilbert space $\mathfrak{L}^2\left(\mathbb{R}, e^{-x^2 / 2}\right)$ which has an inner product given by:
$$\langle f \mid g\rangle=\langle f, g\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) g(x) e^{-x^2 / 2} \mathrm{~d} x \quad \text { where } \quad\|f\|^2=\langle f, f\rangle$$

Do you need your $\alpha_n$ independent from $x$.

$\alpha_n$ is a complex depending only on $n$

What is $\mathbb{Z^*}$?

Can you provide more information like, why you're asking this question, where does the equation come from and what is $\mathbb{Z}^{\ast}$?

@Kevin while I have no idea of the OP motivation, the question asks if $1$ and/or $x$ are in the closed subspace $H$ of $\mathfrak{L}^2\left(\mathbb{R}, e^{-x^2 / 2}\right)$ generated by $e^{nx}$ for integer $n \ne 0$ - note that if $f$ even and $g$ odd (in the space so essentially smaller in absolute value than $e^{x^2/2}$ at $\pm \infty$) we have $\langle f, g\rangle=0$ so $1$ and $x$ are orthogonal; also using $f_n(x)=e^{nx}+e^{-nx}, n \ge 1$ and $g_n(x)=e^{nx}-e^{-nx}, n \ge 1$ we generate $H$ with even and odd functions so one can ask if $1$ is in the even subspace etc

What is the meaning of the infinite sum ? Do you require that the sum is convergent with respect to the norm in $L^2(e^{-x^2/2})$ ?
